# accessing nested relationship in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relation

i have 3 models like below :

```
Date
Property
PropertyDetail
```

and here is my migration for tables i write in order 
Date :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->dateTime('date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Property :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->integer('base_capacity');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and PropertyDetail :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('property_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('property_id');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

i tried to remove unnecessarily fields from migration so to keep it clean so here is my 2 relations bettwen date and proeprties
Datemodel :

```
 public function properties() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
 }
```

and propery model :

```
 public function dates(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Date::class);
}
 public function features(){
    return $this->hasMany(Feature::class);
}
```

ok now finally in my controller i want to do this :

```
 $search = Date::with('properties')
        ->where('date',$someday)->get()


     ->and some how here i want to select the city from the property detail table
;
```

so here is my problem , now i can easily access properties and show thier name but from this relation how can i access features relation and select the city from there should i use joins or some thing there i hope i was clear enough that what i want to do

Comment: Where you used this code? `public function properties() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
 }`

Comment: i used that in my Date model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**Property model:**

```
public function details(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Details::class,'property_details','id','property_id');
}
```

and in **Date model:**

```
 public function properties() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
 }

 public function propertiesDetails() {
     return $this->properties()->with('details');
 }
```

and in your **controller** you can get detail of properties by use:

```
 $search = Date::with('propertiesDetails')
    ->where('date',$someday)->get();
```

now you can access to details of properties.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is that accesing to the nested relationship ??

Comment: Now you can access to city,state,... in your property_details. That was what I thought you needed. Isn't it? @Farshad

Comment: sorry bro  but no i am sorry if i was unclear i wanted to know how to access the third relation with 2 other related tables

Comment: farshadfb here it is